# Short universal single expression for saying a kind of congratulations

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, spoken-english

My friend tells me that their physics teacher is such a good man, he's always so thoughtful of them to learn the lesson and answers all their questions patiently and as simply as possible, while our physics teacher is sort of a grumpy woman(!) and she always talks down to us so we can't ask anything comfortably.

Now, what can I tell her to show my envy of her situation (obviously this is not a jelousy case), and at the same time my good feelings for her situation? I could say:

> "I wish I had your teacher"

...but there are no happy feelings in that. In my own language we have a universal single expression for such moments, that means "I wish I were instead of you and i'm sooo happy for you". What is the equivalent in English?

Does "good for you" work here?  I don't think so because she's done nothing to "gain" that teacher, it's just happened to her by chance.
Good for you is kind of a praise, However, my case is rather sort of a congratulation to her for her good fortune.

Comment: _"I certainly wish I had **your** teacher"_, with strong emphasis on the possessive pronoun, will be understood by native English speakers to convey something very close to what you want.

Comment: @P. E. Dant Thanks, but this is not a universal sentence. Now, say we're talking about weather. Just recently Paris has been so hot, and my friend in london tells me how enjoyable the weather has been in there today, of course I can't say "I certainly wish we had your climate" in this case. This is just a temporary situation in Paris...

Comment: But you see, you _could_ say _"I certainly wish we had **your** weather"_  and, if you would but understand the importance of _emphasis_, be understood exactly as you want. English speakers would grasp your meaning immediately.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I just consulted one of my friends and he said "good for you" can be used in such cases too. Do you think he's right? Of course he also suggested a simple "lucky you!" too. Thanks once again.

Comment: Both expressions convey part of what you want, but they are not as idiomatic in these situations as what I provided. Both would require exposition and context. If you just blurt out _"Good for you!"_, the response will be _"About what?"_

Comment: @M-J *good for you* is sarcastic!

Comment: @Maulik No, not really. Natives believe that it "can" be sarcastic.

Comment: @MaulikV Don't give inaccurate advice, please! The phrase _"good for you"_ is no more sarcastic than _"Hello, beautiful."_ Sarcasm depends on context and tone of voice.

Comment: @M-J *'good for you'* with some more words is not sarcasm. *"Go for that book, it's good for you"* **VS** just *'good for you.'*

Answer (score -1):

You want to convey two expressions:

> To have the same teacher 
>  She is lucky to have that teacher

You said:

> I wish I had your teacher

actually conveys the first part. To include the second expression, you *must* have one more sentence. I am not aware of any word/phrase that conveys both the meanings.

The third option, one sentence that says both the things:

> I wish I was lucky like you *to have him (teacher).*

It includes you being lucky, in place of her, and to have the teacher!

Comment: i'm sorry, but a native speaker would _never_ phrase this sentiment as you have done.

Comment: Of course, I'm not a native! @P.E.Dant